# Transpose Data and Insert Rows - Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have limited VBA knowledge and have done most of my VBA coding by copying and pasting others codes or by recording. So I apologize for not showing any code of my own. Here's my ask, I need to turn this:

```
Column   A   |    B   |     C      |     D      |    E
      random  random 2  Transpose 1 Transpose 2
      random  random 2  Transpose 3 Transpose 4  Transpose 5
```

into this

```
 Column   A   |    B   |     C      |     D      |    E
      random  random 2 
              Transpose 1 
              Transpose 2
      random  random 2  
              Transpose 3 
              Transpose 4  
              Transpose 5
```

Essentially, I have numerous rows that have data starting in column C that needs to be transposed below the row it originally is located in by inserting new rows to match the number of data entries. Is there a way to automate this via VBA code? If possible, please include a description of what each coding line does so that I can follow along.

Comment: Of course there is a way to automate this in VBA :). The idea of this website is however that you first try it yourself and ask specific questions if you get stuck somewhere. There is plenty to find on this website about transposing ranges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want something like this. I tested it twice, it seemed to work and gave me what you have shown in your question (but maybe there are cases where it will fail)

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CustomTranspose()

    ' Understanding this "With" statement is not crucial. We use it mainly for convenience. '
    ' The main thing to note is that we specify what our input is '
    ' and where we want the output to be written to. '
    With ThisWorkbook

        ' Assumes the range you want to work with is on range "A1:E2" on sheet "Sheet1" '
        ' First we read the values into an array. '
        Dim inputArray() As Variant
        inputArray = .Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:M3").Value2

        ' Assumes the range, to which you want to write the "transposed" values,
        ' begins at cell "A1" of sheet "Sheet2"
        Dim firstOutputCell As Range
        Set firstOutputCell = .Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")

    End With

    Dim rowIndex As Long
    Dim columnIndex As Long
    Dim writeIndex As Long
    writeIndex = -1 ' We want it to be 0 after the first increment.

    ' Here we loop over the array (from first row to last row) '
    ' The Lbound and Ubound functions below are just ways of getting the start and end of the array '
    For rowIndex = LBound(inputArray, 1) To UBound(inputArray, 1)

        writeIndex = writeIndex + 1
        ' Copy the first two columns exactly as they are '
        ' We do not need a loop for this, but I use one below anyway'
        For columnIndex = 1 To 2
            firstOutputCell.Offset(writeIndex, columnIndex - 1).Value2 = inputArray(rowIndex, columnIndex)
        Next columnIndex

        ' Loop through the remaining columns (of this row) and write them '
        ' to a new row in column 2 -- effectively transposing them '
        For columnIndex = columnIndex To UBound(inputArray, 2)
            If IsEmpty(inputArray(rowIndex, columnIndex)) Then
                Exit For ' If a blank cell is encountered, we stop looping through the columns and move on to the next row.
            End If
            writeIndex = writeIndex + 1
            firstOutputCell.Offset(writeIndex, 1).Value2 = inputArray(rowIndex, columnIndex)
        Next columnIndex

    Next rowIndex

End Sub
```

There are more comments than code in my answer, but if there's something you still can't follow, leave a comment or something and I will try to explain.

It is always good to show your code/efforts when asking a question.

Comment: This code worked like an absolute charm, and the comments were perfect for helping me tweak the code as I needed. Thank you very much!